# an quite simple code,but TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm in the process of writing one of my first programs and receiving 
an error when testing it . Below is the snippet of code at the beginning of 
my program that's first throwing the issue.I have changed something, it works,thanks @jmcnamara, but i want to show the chart of erreur,from 1 to 100. But i can't arrive.

```
#coding=utf-8
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

import xlsxwriter
import random

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('tableau.xlsx')
worksheeta= workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheetb= workbook.add_worksheet()

Nb_Mesures = 100
critere = 0.03

format=workbook.add_format()    
format.set_border(1)  

format_ave=workbook.add_format()    
format_ave.set_bold()  
format_ave.set_align('center')


format_num=workbook.add_format()
format_num.set_num_format('0.00')   
format_num.set_align('center')

#creerer le worksheeta
worksheeta.write('A1', 'Nb_Mesures', format_ave)
worksheeta.write('B1', 'angle_aleatoire', format_ave)
worksheeta.write('C1', 'angle_mesuré',format_ave)
worksheeta.write('D1','erreur',format_ave)

worksheeta.set_column(0, 1, 13)
worksheeta.set_column(1, 1, 15)
worksheeta.set_column(2, 1, 20)
worksheeta.set_column(3, 1, 10)


data1 = []
data2 = []
data3 = []
data4 = []


for row in range(1, Nb_Mesures + 1):
    b = random.randrange(0, 360)
    c = b*(1+0.02)
    d = ( - b * 0.02)
    data1.append(row)
    data2.append(b)
    data3.append(c)
    data4.append(d)


worksheeta.write_column('A2', data1, format_ave)
worksheeta.write_column('B2' ,data2, format_num)
worksheeta.write_column('C2', data3,  format_num)
worksheeta.write_column('D2', data4, format_num)


charta  = workbook.add_chart({'type' : 'line'})

def chart_series(cur_clo):
        charta.add_series({

            'values': '=Sheeta!$D$'+cur_clo,
            })

for cline in range(2 , 101):
    chart_series(str(cline))

worksheeta.insert_chart('F2',charta)
charta.set_size({'width': 1000, 'height': 500})

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Can we see the specific error you get?

Comment: thank you so much, and i use worksheeta.write_column('A2', data1, format_ave)

Answer (score 2):

You should post complete, working programs. And attaching the error output would be useful too.

There are a lot of errors in the code as it is:

1. There isn't any code to create a workbook, add a worksheet and at the end close the workbook.
2. There isn't any code to create the format objects.
3. `Nb_Mesures` isn't defined.
4. `write_column()` takes a list as a parameter and you are passing it only a single element. That is the error in the (current) subject line.

The last one should probably be:

```
worksheeta.write_column('A2', data1, format_ave)
# etc.
```

Comment: I have followed your advice and changed something, it works,thanks @jmcnamara